# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption AES

Tags: java, sockets, encryption

I had a server written in c# and a client written in Java.

For the encrypt decrypt part, I am using this method

```
 public byte[] EncryptAES(String strText) throws Exception {
    objCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, objSecretKey);
    Log.d("datazz", String.valueOf(strText.getBytes("UTF8")));
    return objCipher.doFinal(strText.getBytes("UTF8"));
}

public byte[] DecryptAES(byte[] tData) throws Exception {
    objCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, objSecretKey);
    return objCipher.doFinal(tData);
}
```

It works properly without any issues,but when I try to send data at much faster speed , I start getting these few errors

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 257
```

It's kinda hard for to trace the issues because when I try to break point  , it works properly , it only happens when I tried to send data at fast speed (EG: sending 5 request to server in one second) and it seems like crashing randomly

Anyone has any idea what causes this? Much appreciate for the help , thanks in advance

Here's the receiving part

```
public void run() {

    tBuffer = null;
    objSocket = new Socket();
    SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(strServerIP, iServerPort);
    bTerminate = false;
    while(!bTerminate){
        try {
            if(!objSocket.isConnected()) { // reconnect feature
                iNumConnection++;
                objSocket.connect(socketAddress);
                // successful connect, reset the connection has be make back to zero
                iNumConnection = 0;
                if(objSocketClientListener != null)
                    objSocketClientListener.Connected();
            }
            else {
                int numCount = objSocket.getInputStream().available();
                if(numCount>0) {
                    byte[] receivedData = new byte[numCount];

                    //bytesReceived += objIn.read(tBuffer, bytesReceived, tBuffer.length - bytesReceived);
                    objSocket.getInputStream().read(receivedData);


                    //for first time initial
                    if (tBuffer == null) {
                        tBuffer = new byte[numCount];
                        System.arraycopy(receivedData, 0, tBuffer, 0, receivedData.length);
                    } else {
                        byte[] newByteArray = new byte[bytesReceived + numCount];
                        System.arraycopy(tBuffer, 0, newByteArray, 0, bytesReceived);
                        System.arraycopy(receivedData, 0, newByteArray, bytesReceived, receivedData.length);

                        tBuffer = new byte[bytesReceived + numCount];
                        System.arraycopy(newByteArray, 0, tBuffer, 0, newByteArray.length);
                    }
                    bytesReceived += numCount;
                    //bytesReceived += objIn.read(tBuffer, bytesReceived, tBuffer.length - bytesReceived);
                    while (bytesReceived > 0 && ((iPos = ArrayHelper.IndexOf(tBuffer, bytesReceived, tDelimiter)) >= 0)) {
                        int iSize = iPos + 1;

                        //byte[] tEncrypted = Base64.decode(Arrays.copyOf(tBuffer, iPos), Base64.DEFAULT);
                        byte[] tEncrypted = Base64.decode(Arrays.copyOf(tBuffer, iSize), Base64.DEFAULT);

                        // remove tBuffer that has be decrypted successful.
                        //System.arraycopy(tBuffer, iSize, tBuffer, 0, (tBuffer.length - iSize));

                        System.arraycopy(tBuffer, iSize, tBuffer, 0, (bytesReceived - iSize));
                        bytesReceived -= iSize;

                        if (tEncrypted != null && tEncrypted.length > 0) {
                            byte[] tDecrypted = objCrypto.DecryptAES(tEncrypted);
                            if (objSocketClientListener != null) {
                                // call the method messageReceived from Activity class
                                Log.d("DataZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZz", new String(tDecrypted, "UTF8") + " ");
                                objSocketClientListener.Received(new String(tDecrypted, "UTF8"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Crittercism.logHandledException(e);
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            resetBuffer();
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (objSocketClientListener != null)
                objSocketClientListener.SocketException(e);
            Stop();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crittercism.logHandledException(e);
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            resetBuffer();
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (objSocketClientListener != null)
                objSocketClientListener.GeneralSocketException(e);
            Stop();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That `Exception` means that you are loosing some bits during sending and then your ciphertext is not a multiple of your block-size (for example `128 bit` for *AES*) anymore.

Comment: loosing some bits during sending? hmm.. any idea how can I prevent the losing bits? but as far as i know , tcp does not allow any data escape? sorry I'm still new into this area , would much appreciate if anyone could help

Comment: It's hard to say with just the little bit of code you provided. It seems so, especially because you also get a `SocketException` that your pipe is broken, i.e. there is some problem with the connection. Could you maybe show the code, you use for receiving?

Comment: I edited the attached code above

Comment: Your code for reading from your socket is very confusing and looks like it might be broken. Can you describe what that code is supposed to do? It seems like you want to read enough bytes to find a delimiter, then base64-decode everything up to, but not including, the delimiter?

Comment: yeap , that's correct , erm..which part looks like it might be broken? thanks in advance !